# what is the parametric function of the new Bezier curve?

Tags: matrices, bezier-curve

The cubic Bezier curve can be given in matrix form as

[image]

If a cubic Bezier curve is rotated by an angle 30  around x-axis what is the parametric function of the new Bezier curve?

Comment: Do you mean to say that the curve is given by setting $y = P(x)$?  That is, are you referring to the curve parameterized by
$$
(t,P(t)); \quad t \in [0,1]?

$$

Comment: I suspect that $P_0$, $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$ are 2D or 3D points. So, the equation of the curve is $u \mapsto P(t)$ for $u \in [0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are starting with the curve parameterized by
$$
c(t) = \pmatrix{t\\ P(t)}
$$
In order to rotate a parameterized curve about the origin, apply the rotation matrix.  That is, we multiply $c(t)$ on the left by the matrix
$$
R_{30^\circ} = 
\pmatrix{
\cos(30^\circ) & -\sin(30^\circ)\\
\sin (30^\circ) & \cos(30^\circ)
} = 
\frac 12 \pmatrix{
\sqrt 3 & -1\\
1 & \sqrt 3
}
$$

Answer (score 1):

To get the parametric equation of the rotated curve, you just use the rotated control points. So, you rotate the original four control points using the rotation matrix given by omnomnomnom, to get four new control points. Plugging these four rotated control points into your matrix equation will give the equation of the rotated curve.

If this is a homework question, I suspect that it's meant to illustrate this idea -- to rotate a Bezier curve (or transform it using any affine transformation), you simply have to apply this transformation to the control points. This is a very nice property of Bezier curves.